# How to make shared step defination file

Tags: unit-testing, bdd, specflow

I am new to spec-flow and just start using it . I found that if a step is same in 2 different scenarios then spec-flow write that step only once . I need to know how spec-flow recognize that a step is duplicate .

And another scenario is that how can i make a shared file for multiple step definition files . Like

Suppose i have 10-15 different files in which `Given` step is same i want to make a separate file . Where i write that step and all other files gets that step from there . Is it possible .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `[Binding]`s in SpecFlow are global, so you already have shared steps.

The problem that comes from this is if you have start defining your bindings in different classes and your are using fields to hold data between steps. See [Sharing data between bindings](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings)